# Vlookup returning N/A when use string as a "Lookup Value"

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vlookup

I have problem using vlookup in excel, I want to get Product Group but using Food Name as Lookup Value, But it return N/A

I'm not using Product ID Instead because It has same Product ID in my database for multiple product.

Can Anyone Help?

[image]

Here's my vlookup formula
 `=VLOOKUP(R19;$M$18:$O$21;3;0)`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vlookup only lookup values on first column. I assume you lookup table will start from `N` column. Something like-

```
 =VLOOKUP(R18;$N$18:$O$21;2;0)
```

Better to use `INDEX/MATCH` or `XLOOKUP()` if you have.

```
=INDEX($O$18:$O$21,MATCH(R18,$N$18:$N$21,0))
```